# css and html div issue ...why when I increase div height add a top margin for a background image?

Tags: html, css

This is my First design at codepen...

http://codepen.io/butterfly85/pen/hitrK

I have an simple issue .. when I increase div height add unwanted top margin for background image.

I want to remove the margin of background image caused by div's height.

```
<body>
<header>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>|
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>|
        <li><a href="#"> About Us  </a></li>|
        <li><a href="#"> Contact Us  </a></li>
    </ul>

    <p> Title goes here </p>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Your Email"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</header><!--ENDING HEADER -->
<!-- content -->
<div class="img1"><p> paragraph goes her<br ><a> More Details   </a></p></div>
<div class="img2"><p>paragraph goes her<br ><a>More Details  </a></p></div>
<div class="img3"><p>paragraph goes her<br ><a>More Details  </a></p></div>

</body>
```

And css :

```
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0; 
    }
body{
width:800px;
min-height:100px;
margin:0 auto;  
background:url(http://str-ly.com/up/uploads/str-ly.com13810941559511.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size:800px 500px;
background-position:center;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:24px;
color:white;
}
/* ----- HEADER ---------*/
header{
text-align:center;

}
img{
border-radius:80%;  

}

input[placeholder]{
text-align:right;
padding:10px;
border:0;   
}
input[type="submit"]{
 margin:30px 0 0 0;
 padding:10px;  
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:20px;
}

ul{
 list-style:none;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
li{

 display:inline;
}
a{
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
}
/*---------- CONTENT -------------*/
div{
 height:150px;
}

p{
 color:#000;
}
div p{
 color:#ff0055;
 text-align:right;
 padding-right:50px;
}
p a{
 position:absolute;
 left:600px;

}
```

please don't vote me by negative.  :)

thanks

Comment: please give us some more information on what you're trying to do and also point out what div you're talking about!

Comment: please post relevant code here too

Comment: ^ jsFiddles also help! :)

Comment: I want to remove the margin of background image caused by div height.

Comment: Your question should be self-contained, that is, the relevant code should be available right here on-site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `background-position:center;` to `background-position:top;`...not 100% sure I understand the question but that is my first instinct upon seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

add position:absolute in div css property... hope this helps

Comment: I did this although it remove a top margin but cause an issue in three  div

Comment: i got that one wait i may help u

Comment: margin-top:-50px; if height = 150px and if height = 200 then margin-top: -100px; hope this help remove that position:absoulte

Comment: ya he is right background-position:top i haven't seen that sorry to waste your time

Comment: No I waste your time not you thanks a lot